# SQL option to display the results on evaluating the column values

Tags: sql

I have a table as shown below

| SourceCustomerId | HasTaxBenifit | HasCollateral | HasLoan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100021 | No | No | No |
| 100022 | No | No | Yes |
| 100023 | No | Yes | No |
| 100024 | No | Yes | Yes |
| 100025 | Yes | No | No |
| 100026 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 100027 | Yes | Yes | No |
| 100028 | YEs | Yes | Yes |

On Using a select statement, the expected output.

| SourceCustomerId | BinaryTaxBenifit | BinaryCollateral | BinaryLoan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100021 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 100022 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 100023 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 100024 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 100025 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 100026 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 100027 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 100028 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

The logic is every column has  a binary equivalent and they will be having a value of 0 if the columns are having a value 'No'. else 'Yes'. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when HasTaxBenifit = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as BinaryTaxBenefit,
       . . . 
from t;
```